# Automatically give colours to shapefiles in different layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, attribute-table, style, color

I'm in the final stage of my floodmap and I want to colour the River basin districts based on the Total floods in the area. When there are 0 floods it has to be white, 1-2 floods -> green, 3-5 -> yellow and go on to red. For example all the river basins from Austria has their own attribute tabel (not all in one table). as you can see below.

[image]

I already made a colourstyle which i would like to use. It is working now if I would do it manually, but I would like to have it automatically because in the future the floods will count on. For example if there is one flood, it could be 3 or 4 in 2020. Now the colour is green because of the one flood, but with 3 or 4 it has to be yellow.

Later on I am going to link my Excel to arcmap (have no idea how, but that's a later problem), so when I add a flood in excel it will automatically change from attributes and colours in arcmap.

Does somebody know a solution for this problem?
(the give colours based on attributes to different layers problem)